# Missing AppBar on BottomNavigationBar page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **`bottomNavigationBar`** and when I click on **`Page2`** I should land on a page with an **`AppBar`** with an icon on the top right have the screen but when I click it, instead, **I have only an empty black page**.

This is the `code` :

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home_page(),
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(),
    Page4(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Esplora',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Colori',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Altro',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Profilo',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code of **`Page2`** :

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2_HomeState createState() => _Page2_HomeState();
}

class _Page2_HomeState extends State<Page2_Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          navForm(),
        ],
        title: Text("Page2"),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget navForm() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
      onPressed: () => navigateToForm(context),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know why the **`AppBar`** isn't there, maybe I'm not dealing good with indices?

Or the **`AppBar`** isn't well implemented, this is my first time dealing with the **`BottomNavigationBar`** so I think the error is in one of these **2** elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added body in Scaffold. that's why whenever you Tap on tab you are not getting result you want.
You can add body in your scaffold like this:

```
 body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
```

Full code of build:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Page2(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Esplora',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Colori',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Altro',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Profilo',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
      body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a body to the scaffold home page like this :

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: _widgetOption[_selectedIndex ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
```